# How to create a pivot table that pulls data from multiple tabs?

Tags: tabs, pivot

I have a spreadsheet with multiple tabs (for different phases of projects).
I would like to create a pivot table with that sums the labor days and contract amounts from each quarter for all phases. I do not want the breakdown per phase - just total labor days and total contract amount per quarter.

[Tab example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGXBx.png)
[Pivot table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gO9PH.png)

I'm new to pivot tables - but the videos online suggest data cannot be pulled from multiple tabs.